# Sencha Touch 2.1: Form Panel Keyboard hides active Textfield on Android

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

When I tap a textfield at the bottom of the screen, the keyboard appears and hides the active element. On iOS, it works perfect.

I'm able to scroll the form, so the textfield is in the visible area, but that's not nice at all. Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug as I have the same behaviour in this example from Sencha Touch itself: docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/touch-build/examples/forms/

If on this form:

[image]

I tap in the textfield of "Bio", the keyboard hides the textfield, instead of scrolling the textfield up to have it visible while typing:

[image]

Comment: a screenshot might help understand it more

Comment: Does it happen after the second time you click it or every time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is definitively a known-issue, I've seen this many times on Android. The only thing you can try to do is listen for a focus event on the input field and then scroll to the element. You might have to play around with the right `Y`-value, which suits your situation best.

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    name: 'bio',
    label: 'Bio',
    maxRows: 10,
    listeners: {
        focus: function(comp, e, eopts) {
            var ost = comp.element.dom.offsetTop;
            this.getParent().getParent().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, ost);
        }
    }
},
```

This works for me. If you need any help implementing this, let me know!

[image]

Comment: I changed it to `comp.getParent().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, e.target.clientHeight);`, but it still doesn't work, unfortunately... the code is called and in desktop-chrome it seems like it scrolls a little bit, on android it doesn't...

Comment: Well, that's probably not going to work because you will target the `fieldset`. In my own working version of the Sencha Form example i have `this.getParent().getParent().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, e.target.clientHeight);` (this refers to the scroller of the form).

If this still isn't working, can you see if any javascript errors are thrown in Android?

Comment: I just added a demo where you can see my example working on the `bio` field.

Comment: still no luck with my android in your example... when tapping into the bio-field, my keyboard hides the field

Comment: still no luck, unfortunately... please see my video here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/119600/sencha.MOV (~ 10 MB)

Comment: @swalkner Hey man, i finally managed to get a really decent solution after a few hours. Take a look at the example and see it works (Make sure your not caching anything!). If it is still not working, would you post your device and your OS version?

Comment: looks promising now :) I'll have a look at it later!

Answer (score 6):

Less intrusive solution:

on Application launch method add the following lines:

```
launch: function() {
    if (Ext.os.is.Android) { //maybe target more specific android versions.
        Ext.Viewport.on('painted', function() {
            Ext.Viewport.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        });
    }
    // ... rest of the launch method here
}
```

This works just fine on many cases I have been testing on. Both Cordova and Chrome implementations. You just need to take care, in case of Cordova/Phonegap app, that the fullscreen is set to false. (Tested on Cordova 3.5)

Comment: Wow , this worked after trying a lot of things. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

The "Ext.Viewport.on('painted'"-solution gave me scrolling problem. The whole page could not be scrolled after orientation change, because viewport height would then be larger than window height. 
(Ext.Viewport.getHeight() will not be the same as Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight() after orientation change.)

Made a work around using overidden input:

Create a file app/overrides/field/Input.js

```
Ext.define('myApp.overrides.field.Input', {
  override: 'Ext.field.Input',

  initialize: function() {
    var me = this;

    // Solves problem that screen keyboard hides current textfield
    if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
        this.element.on({
            scope      : this,
            tap        : 'onTap',
        });
    }

    me.callParent();
  },

  onResize: function(input) {
    var me = input;
    //if input is not within window
    //defer so that resize is finished before scroll
    if(me.element.getY() + me.element.getHeight() > window.innerHeight) {
        Ext.Function.defer(function() {
            me.element.dom.scrollIntoView(false);
        }, 100);
    }
  },

  // Solves problem that screen keyboard hides current textfield in e.g. MyTimeRowForm
  //old solution with Viewport.on('painted', gave scroll problem when changeing orientation
  onTap: function(e) {
    me = this;
    window.addEventListener( "resize", function resizeWindow () {
        me.onResize(me);
        window.removeEventListener( "resize", resizeWindow, true );
    }, true );
  },   
});
```

And add it to app.js

```
requires: ['myApp.overrides.field.Input']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may subscribe on show/hide events of keyboard and compensate input's offset. It's been tested on Android 4.2 & 4.4 (HTC One & Nexus 7).

```
if (Ext.os.is.Android4 && Ext.os.version.getMinor() >= 2) {
    (function() {
        var inputEl = null;
        var onKeyboardShow = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!inputEl) {
                    return;
                }
                var currentClientHeight = window.document.body.clientHeight;
                var elRect = inputEl.getBoundingClientRect();
                var elOffset = elRect.top + elRect.height;
                if (elOffset <= currentClientHeight) {
                    return;
                }
                var offset = currentClientHeight - elOffset;
                setOffset(offset);
            }, 100);
        };
        var onKeyboardHide = function() {
            setOffset(0);
        };
        var setOffset = function(offset) {
            var el = Ext.Viewport.innerElement.dom.childNodes[0];
            if (el) {
                el.style.setProperty('top', offset + 'px');
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onKeyboardHide, false);
            document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onKeyboardShow, false);
        }, false);
        Ext.define('Ext.field.Input.override', {
            override: 'Ext.field.Input',
            onFocus: function(e){
                inputEl = e.target;
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },
            onBlur: function(e){
                inputEl = null;
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        })
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked better for me

```
{
   xtype: 'passwordfield',
   name: 'pass',
   listeners: {
      focus: function (comp, e, eopts) {
        var contr = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
          if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
            var ost = comp.element.dom.offsetTop;
            contr.getParent().getParent().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, ost, true);
          }
        }, 400);
      }
   }
}
```