# Keyboard hides input field after sencha touch 2.2.1 native packaging

Tags: android, extjs, android-keypad

I packaged an sencha touch app to native for android. Now I have this strange behaviour. In the web view when the focus was made on the first name field the view adjusted it self. But post native build see the register button is hidden and the app did not adjust. can anyone help me with a solution? I have attached the screens. See the register button.

**After packaging**
[image]

**Before packaging in the browser**
[image]

Comment: I see you're using Touch 2.2 - what version of Android? And is this the simulator, or on an actual device?

Comment: this is actual device. i am on google nexus 7. i have also tested it on samsung galaxy S

Answer (score 1):

Seems duplicate with this question: [Sencha Touch 2.1: Form Panel Keyboard hides active Textfield on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596111/sencha-touch-2-1-form-panel-keyboard-hides-active-textfield-on-android)

Since I met the same issue, after googling I've found this issue in Sencha Forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260241